# Remixd install error : glob-parent <5.1.2

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Remixd on mac, but get this error:

```
glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
Regular expression denial of service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
No fix available
node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/chokidar
    @remix-project/remixd  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/@remix-project/remixd

3 high severity vulnerabilities
```

I posted this on Ethereum Stack Exchange, but havent had much luck. I am pretty new to programming and dont want to break my computer.
Would it make sense for me to upgrade the webpack-dev-server? Or to upgrade watchpack? Thank you so much (: please let me know if I can make the question clearer/ improve upon it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error and remixd was not installed. However when I did a global install using -g flag i.e.,

```
npm install -g @remix-project/remixd
```

The installation was successful. I appreciate this does not explain the vulnerabilities error we're seeing.